# Sequential javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have an application using JSF 2.0, javascript and query 1.9. I have a situation where I need to conditionally render a component depending on the result of a bean's method. The logic right now is that when clicking a button, javascript shows a component with a success message in certain .css style. Whan I need is that when clicking that same button, javascript calls the bean's method, and depending on the result of that method, display the same success component or another component explaining why it failed. I know that neither javascript nor jquery can't directly call a bean's method, so instead, javascript would click a hidden button that calls the bean's method. So, generally, this is what I want to do.

Beans code

```
public boolean getValidated(){
    return validated;
}

public void setValidated(boolean value){
    validated = value;
}

public void myMethod(){
    ....
    if(condition){
        validated = true;
    }else{
        validated = false;
    }
}
```

JSF CODE

```
<h:commandButton onclick="magic()/>
<h:commandButton id="hiddenButton" action="#{bean.myMethod}" style="display:none;"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
function magic(){
  document.getElementById('hiddenButton').click();
  if(#{bean.validated}){
     NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.success,['<strong>The requested updates have been saved.</strong> <a href="" class="right"><strong>Undo Change</strong></a>'],NI.pnx.messaging.messageTimeoutSpeeds.slow);
  }else{
     NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.error,['<strong>The requested updates have not been saved.</strong> <a href="" class="right"><strong>Undo Change</strong></a>'],NI.pnx.messaging.messageTimeoutSpeeds.slow);
  }
}
  // ]]>
</script>
```

The issue is that javascript seems to be checking the validated attribute before the myMethod() is even done. So, it pretty much clicks on the hidden button and immediately asks for the value of the boolean, and the myMethod() is not even done yet.

How can I make javascript behave in a sequential way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the command button conditionally render the script inline itself.

```
<h:commandButton value="magic" action="#{bean.myMethod}">
    <f:ajax render="script">
</h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="script">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{facesContext.postback}">
        <![CDATA[
            if (#{bean.validated}) {
                NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.success,['<strong>The requested updates have been saved.</strong> <a href="" class="right"><strong>Undo Change</strong></a>'],NI.pnx.messaging.messageTimeoutSpeeds.slow);
            } else {
                NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.error,['<strong>The requested updates have not been saved.</strong> <a href="" class="right"><strong>Undo Change</strong></a>'],NI.pnx.messaging.messageTimeoutSpeeds.slow);
            }
        ]]>
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If you're using a true JSF validator, then you can also just use `#{facesContext.validationFailed}` instead of manually keeping track of it in a bean.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you may find [PrimeFaces `<p:growl>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf) more helpful than this reinvention of the wheel.

Comment: Can't use primefaces... Local maven repository. Still, that command is new to me, so I'm going to check it out. Thanks, BalusC!